# Tracking changes made to a folder in Delphi

Tags: windows, file, delphi, file-io, directory

I need to writing a Delphi program which will monitor a folder for changes (add, update, rename and removal of files).

I have seen suggestions to use theTShellChangeNotifier. Is this the correct solution for this problem? How should I use it?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20160518172109/http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/directory-watch/ is very good and free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863135/why-does-readdirectorychangesw-omit-events) might help. mghie's answer shows how to properly use `ReadDirectoryChangesW`.

Answer (score 5):

I think this article will help you: [Monitoring System Shell Changes using Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/l/aa030403b.htm)

Basically it analyzes the TShellChangeNotifier, discards it and then goes for a TSHChangeNotify which is basically a wrapper for the [SHChangeNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762118%28VS.85%29.aspx) windows api function.

Comment: It seem to be monitor the entire file system, I can only limit it to monitor local hard drives. Is there a way where I could specify the folder it will only monitor? I am worry it might eat up a lot of unnecessary resources. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think you can, at least with the SHChangeNotify. Nonetheless is shouldn't eat up a lot of resources, you'll just ignore whatever doesn't affects the path you're interested in, windows will monitor all the changes wheter you're listening or not :)

Answer (score 0):

i suggest using [madShell](http://help.madshi.net/madShell.htm)

```
RegisterShellEvent(ShellEvent, pathToMonitor, false, [seItemCreated, seItemRenamed]);

//

procedure Tform.ShellEvent(event: TShellEventType; const obj1, obj2: IShellObj; drive: char; value: cardinal);
var
  filename: string;
  isReady: boolean;
begin
  if (event = seItemCreated) then
    filename := obj1.Path
  else if (event = seItemRenamed) then
    filename := obj2.Path
  else
    exit;

  // try to open to ensure it's read for reading
  repeat
    try
      TfileStream.Create(filename, fmOpenRead + fmShareExclusive).Free;
      isReady := true;
    except
      isReady := false;
      sleep(250);
    end;
  until (isReady) or (not FileExists(filename));

  OutputDebugString(pChar('ShellEvent: ' + filename));

end;
```

Comment: I don't know madShell but that `repeat` loop looks very ugly. It continually throws and catches exceptions and has a hard-coded delay...not what I expect from a clean and efficient solution...