# Recursive Use of ReadDirectoryChanges

Tags: windows, delphi, file-io, delphi-xe

I want to watch all changes in a directory recursively, i.e. if watching `C:\` I want to receive notifications for

```
C:\1.txt
C:\A\1.txt
```

If I use `ReadDirectoryChanges` with `watchSubtree` option enabled, it reports only

```
C:\1.txt
C:\A
```

It does not work recursively.

How can I make it work recursively? Do I really need to call `ReadDirectoryChanges`for each subdirectory recusively? What if new subdirectories are created / subdirectories get deleted?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @Smasher, the `ReadDirectoryChanges` function can works recursively, maybe the problem is in your implementation of this function.please share the code which you are using in order to get help.

Comment: @RRUZ: I would be more than happy if you are right, but I don't think so. I'm using the code posted by @mghie in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863135/why-does-readdirectorychangesw-omit-events/864050#864050 He mentions this fact as well. Also this blog article http://qualapps.blogspot.com/2010/05/understanding-readdirectorychangesw.html states it, but without a solution as well.

Comment: @RRUZ: just to be clear: it DOES report the change of `C:\A\1.txt` but the file name in the notification is `C:\A` and not `C:\A\1.txt`.

Comment: I see nothing in those articles about the bWatchSubtree parameter not working, except that the Stack Overflow answer mentions a caveat about *deletion* of files and how you won't be notified about every single file. Please give more details about what doesn't work and what you were expecting. Also note the recommendations *against* using this API to monitor changes to an entire drive. Use the change journal for that.

Comment: @Smasher try this implementation http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidD3135FB08B930CFAC5A92ECBA3D67C83852488B2.aspx?s=zip#L30, i just tested and works ok (this means which report the full name of the file modified), just need a few changes to omit warnings in delphi XE. just a tip, in the past i have problems (some notifications was lost) when I trying to monitor the system root folder recursively using the `ReadDirectoryChanges` function. check this sample image which shows the full filename in the notifications http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12733424/MonitorDemo.png

Comment: @Rob: "mentions a caveat about deletion of files and how you won't be notified about every single file" That's exactly what I mean. I need a notification for every single file. I don't plan to use this on a whole drive. It was just an (not very well-chosen) example.

Comment: @RRUZ: thanks for the link and your help. I'll try this when I get back to work tomorrow.

Comment: You can also look at my component that does the same: http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/directory-watch/ It works ok for me in production code.

Comment: Thank you all! I got it working. If you post your links as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Runner: Both helped :) I read both and then rewrote parts of my own code, which made it work. I probably took more code out of your link though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at [DirectoryWatch](http://cromis.net/blog/downloads/directory-watch) component which works. I use it in production code so I know it works correctly, even for subdirs.

Comment: I accept this because it helped me to get it right. Thanks to @RRUZ for the good link as well. BTW: do you handle the buffer overflow case in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [change journals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you're trying to watch the whole disk.