# Delphi: TJvChangeNotify/TShellChangeNotifier - file's name

Tags: delphi, filenames, change-notification

How to know what file was changed (it's name) on Change Event of TJvChangeNotify (JEDI) or TShellChangeNotifier?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both components use `FindFirstChangeNotification` to monitor changes. As indicated in its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the function does not provide information on what triggered the notification. As such the only possible way to find out what happened using these components is to keep a snapshot of the monitored folder and perform a comparison after a change occurs.

If you decide to use [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as suggested by `FindFirstChangeNotification`'s documentation, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863135/why-does-readdirectorychangesw-omit-events/864050#864050). Or instead, if you decide to use [`SHChangeNotifyRegister`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) see this [article](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/l/aa030403a.htm).